# Frame title - path to current file

Tags: init-file, frames

In my config file, how do I set the frame title so that it shows:

1. The buffer name
2. If a file buffer, show the path to the file without the filename

So something like this:

`.emacs.el -- D:\Dropbox\dotfiles`

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this give the name you want:

```
(set-frame-name (format "%s%s" (buffer-name)
            (if-let (fn (buffer-file-name))
                (format " -- %s" (file-name-directory fn))
              "")))
```

If you use an older emacs (less than v25) try:

```
(set-frame-name (format "%s%s"
            (buffer-name)
            (let ((bfn (buffer-file-name)))
              (if bfn
                  (format " -- %s" (file-name-directory bfn))
                ""))))
```

If it does maybe you can add it to a hook function to run it, e.g. when you open a file or something.

Comment: That gives me an error: `Symbol's function definition is void: if-let`

Comment: I guess you use an older emacs? I added another version for an older one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in my init

```
(setq-default frame-title-format
          '(("" invocation-name "@" system-name "\t")
            (buffer-file-name "%f" "%b")))
```

Basically it handles a buffer for a file or a special buffer.  As for the format of the file path, you could play around with `buffer-file-name`.

Comment: The part that I'm having trouble with is getting the path without the filename, and only including `--` if a its a file buffer. So I need to find a way to remove the filename from `%f`, and only show `--` if `%f` exists